# When the application is closed in Android 10, the foreground service does not work and closes completely

Tags: android

In Xiaomi 9c Android 10, while my foreground service is running while the application is in the background, when I close the application, my foreground service is completely closed. Below is my foreground service and androidmanifest file.

my foreground service

```
override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        createNotificationChannel()
        startCallStateListener()
        serviceRunning = true
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
         this.username = intent?.getStringExtra("username") ?: ""

        startForeground(notificationId, builder.build())
        serviceRunning = true
        return START_STICKY
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        serviceRunning = false
        stopCallStateListener()
    }

    private fun createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            channel = NotificationChannel(
                "example_service",
                "Example Service",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            )
            channel.lightColor = NotificationCompat.COLOR_DEFAULT
            channel.lockscreenVisibility = Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE
            manager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }
        createNotification()
    }

    private fun createNotification() {
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        //val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)

        builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "example_service")
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("")
            .setContentText("")
            .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
           // .addAction(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Devam Et", pendingIntent)
    }
```

My AndroidManifest.xml files

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <application
        android:label="ARAMA"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
        <service
            android:name=".ExampleService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" 
            android:foregroundServiceType="phoneCall"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

what should I do ?